# Label Scipy Dendrogram by Average Cluster Value

Tags: python, scipy, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I have a dendrogram calculated from some data points labeled 0-9.

How do I retrieve which datapoints (0-9) are in each node from the output of `scipy.cluster.hiearchy.dendrogram`? I want to label each node by its average (x,y) value.
I know I can retrieve the clusters using the clustering algorithm (Scikit learn agglomerative clustering for example) but I want to label the whole dendrogram by the average value in each node.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
import numpy as np


np.random.seed(4711)  
X = np.random.uniform(-10,10,size=(10,2))
labels=[i for i in range(len(X))]
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1])

dist=squareform(pdist(X))

Y = linkage(squareform(dist), method='complete')
Z1 =dendrogram(Y, labels=labels, orientation='left')
```

For example, in the dendrogram above I would like to label the node which joins points 6,4 as the average of the x and y values of point 6 and point 4. `(X[6]+X[4])/2` etc.

[image: Dendrogram output]

`scipy.cluster.hiearchy.dendrogram` outputs a dictionary with the `color_list`, `icoord`, `dcoord`, `ivl`, `leaves`, `leaves_colorlist`. I feel like I should be able to use `ivl` combined with `leaves` and the coordinates but I'm not sure how to interpret it/use it.

[(documentation for dendrogram)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.dendrogram.html)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `leaf_label_func` parameter.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(4711)  
# X will be interpreted as cluster centers
X = np.random.uniform(-10,10,size=(10,2))
def llf(id):
    return f'Cluster #{id} @ {X[id]}'
Y = linkage(pdist(X), method='complete')
Z1 =dendrogram(Y, leaf_label_func=llf, get_leaves=True, orientation='left')
```

I also replaced a `squareform(squareform(pdist(dist)))` by `pdist(dist)`.